# Delete one of my google account from marshmallow

Tags: gmail

I have 3 linked acccount on my phone for gmail,

I want to access one of the account from destkop only and don't want to link that account on my phone,

How do i completely remove that account from my phone? what are the steps?

When i click on remove account, it goes to browser login, will it completely remove my account or it will remove from phone only?

I dont want to completely remove it.

Answer (score 2):

- Once, you click on remove account, it will lead you to a browser page where you have to log in with your account password. It will warm you that the following information pertaining to that account will be deleted from your **device**. Follow the steps to delete

[image]
[image]
[image]

- **[Deleting the account affects only your device and you can still access it from desktop](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/8154?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en&oco=1)**

> The only way to sign out of the Gmail app is to remove your entire account from your phone or tablet.

- See "Remove your Google account from your device" section, which says

> Removing the account from your phone or tablet **won't delete the account itself**, so you'll still be able to use it on a computer or other devices.

(Emphasis supplied)

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below steps to delete extra account you added into your Gmail app on Andriod phone :

1. Go to setting
2. Search the tab named : "accounts" there look for
   "others accounts" and click on it
3. there look for "others accounts" and click on it
4. you will see the "other" tab
5. then search for "Google" click on it for more into setting of it
6. there you will see the "more" option click it
7. you will have 2 options "Sync now" and " Remove account"
8. Please do select the remove account which ever you want to remove.

Hope this will help.